# Java application deployment failing

Tags: java, javafx

I am having this `build:xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="TeleMart" default="default" basedir="." xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project TeleMart.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
    <target name="-post-jfx-deploy">
       <fx:deploy verbose="true" width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}" 
                 nativeBundles="all"
                 outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" outfile="${application.title}">
          <fx:application name="${application.title}" mainClass="${javafx.main.class}" />
          <fx:resources>
              <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="TeleMart.jar"/>
              <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}/lib" includes="*"/>
          </fx:resources>
          <fx:info title="${application.title}" vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
      </fx:deploy>          
    </target>
</project>
```

However, when I try to `Clean and Build` using `NetBeans 8.0.2`, I get this error:

```
ant -f /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart jfx-rebuild
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/build/built-clean.properties
Deleting directory /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/build
Updating property file: /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/build/built-jar.properties
Created dir: /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/build/classes
Created dir: /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/build/empty
Created dir: /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
Compiling 33 source files to /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/build/classes
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Copying 23 files to /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/build/classes
compile:
Created dir: /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/dist
Copying 12 files to /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/dist/lib
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
Launching <fx:jar> task from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../lib/ant-javafx.jar
Warning: From JDK7u25 the Codebase manifest attribute should be used to restrict JAR repurposing.
         Please set manifest.custom.codebase property to override the current default non-secure value '*'.
Launching <fx:deploy> task from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../lib/ant-javafx.jar
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
The jar jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar has a main class org.jboss.jandex.Main that does not match the declared main com.hassanalthaf.telemart.Main
The jar javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar has a main class javassist.CtClass that does not match the declared main com.hassanalthaf.telemart.Main
  Using default package resource [Bundle config file]  (add package/macosx/Info.plist to the class path to customize)
  Using default package resource [icon]  (add package/macosx/TeleMart.icns to the class path to customize)
Creating app bundle: /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/dist/bundles/TeleMart.app
Did not find a key matching 'Developer ID Application: '
  Config files are saved to /var/folders/2l/wftgxk5j2bg2fwqf44c6cvyc0000gn/T/fxbundler6145553270790317153/macosx. Use them to customize package.
The jar jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar has a main class org.jboss.jandex.Main that does not match the declared main com.hassanalthaf.telemart.Main
The jar javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar has a main class javassist.CtClass that does not match the declared main com.hassanalthaf.telemart.Main
Building DMG package for TeleMart
  Using default package resource [Bundle config file]  (add package/macosx/Info.plist to the class path to customize)
  Using default package resource [icon]  (add package/macosx/TeleMart.icns to the class path to customize)
Did not find a key matching 'Developer ID Application: '
  Config files are saved to /var/folders/2l/wftgxk5j2bg2fwqf44c6cvyc0000gn/T/fxbundler8097509373603543209/macosx. Use them to customize package.
  Using default package resource [dmg background]  (add package/macosx/TeleMart-background.png to the class path to customize)
  Using default package resource [volume icon]  (add package/macosx/TeleMart-volume.icns to the class path to customize)
Using default package resource [script to run after application image is populated]  (add package/macosx/TeleMart-post-image.sh to the class path to customize)
  Using default package resource [DMG setup script]  (add package/macosx/TeleMart-dmg-setup.scpt to the class path to customize)
  Config files are saved to /var/folders/2l/wftgxk5j2bg2fwqf44c6cvyc0000gn/T/fxbundler8097509373603543209/macosx. Use them to customize package.
/Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/nbproject/jfx-impl.xml:3438: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/nbproject/jfx-impl.xml:1465: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/nbproject/jfx-impl.xml:3093: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/nbproject/jfx-impl.xml:2462: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/build.xml:57: Error: Bundler "DMG Installer" (dmg) failed to produce a bundle.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 14 seconds)
```

What would be the possible reason behind this and the best solution to solve the problem? Feel free to ask any extra codes or whatsoever. The most weirdest part here is that I can run this application normally using the 'Run' option. I don't get any sort of errors or exceptions, however, I get a large amount of messages, but I don't think they affect this by any means:

```
ant -f /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart jfxsa-run
init:
Deleting: /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/build/built-jar.properties
compile:
Deleting directory /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/dist/lib
Copying 12 files to /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/dist/lib
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
jfx-deployment:
jar:
Copying 36 files to /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/dist/run2074822078
jfx-project-run:
Executing /Users/hassan/NetBeansProjects/TeleMart/TeleMart/dist/run2074822078/TeleMart.jar using platform /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
Jan 02, 2016 5:28:40 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.6.Final}
Jan 02, 2016 5:28:40 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jan 02, 2016 5:28:40 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Jan 02, 2016 5:28:40 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Jan 02, 2016 5:28:40 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Jan 02, 2016 5:28:40 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Jan 02, 2016 5:28:41 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Jan 02, 2016 5:28:41 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Jan 02, 2016 5:28:41 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jan 02, 2016 5:28:41 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [null] at URL [jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/telemart]
Jan 02, 2016 5:28:41 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Jan 02, 2016 5:28:41 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Jan 02, 2016 5:28:41 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Jan 02, 2016 5:28:42 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

[TeleMart jfx-impl.xml](http://pastebin.com/BemwskPr)
[TeleMart-Preloader jfx-impl.xml](http://pastebin.com/NLtW4vwm)

**Any exceptional answer will receive a bounty ranging from 50 to 200 reputation from me depending on the quality.**

Comment: The problem seems to be in `jfx-impl.xml` . Can you add the relevant lines in your post?

Comment: @holzst sure, I'll add both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the NetBeans IDE. It fixed everything for me when I updated NetBeans.